# Cron job of my custom command in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, cron, task

I know there is Laravel 5.* now but for many reasons I'm using Laravel 4.2

I have a custom command, and in the fire() method, I import a file and seed the information in my database, so my class is some like this

```
class SeedDataFile extends Command {
    protected $name = 'import:file';

    public function fire(){
    $command = 'mongoimport --db things --collection users --type csv --file file.csv --headerline';
    $result = exec($command, $output, $return);
    }
}
```

I want the file that is seeding data, i.e. every 12 hours (considering the file every 12 hours is changing with new data), but as an user I don't want to type the command in my terminal:

```
php artisan import:file
```

..every 12 hours (I just want to upload the new file to my project).

So the cron job is where I do all the work, but I don't want to do this:

```
crontab -e
```

and edit the file

I want to setup the schedule of my command in one class o somewhere in the code, and automatically the custom command is running everyday until a determined date.

Is this possible? Or I have to configure the crontab file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at this package, description says that it does exactly what you want

https://github.com/Indatus/dispatcher

Comment: Thank you! Is exactly what I need.! :)

Comment: Glad to help! Please tick as an answer so other people can benefit from this

Answer (score 0):

As is Laravel 4.2 does not offer this type of functionality. In fact you'll need to set up 1 cron job for this functionality no matter the version you're using.

Newer versions of Laravel do indeed provide [this functionality](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling#defining-schedules), but they still require you to set up 1 cron job (scheduler on Windows) at highest frequency available for Laravel's command `php artisan schedule:run`.

If you want to have scheduling of your commands in your code (rather than cron file) you could replicate what newer versions of Laravel do.

**1.** you would create a "master" command, let's call it `TaskSchedulerCommand` and let's say it's signature is `php artisan schedule`.

**2.** you would create a cronjob at highest frequency on the `TaskSchedulerCommand` like this: * * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule`

**3.** you would write all the scheduling logic of other commands within the `TaskSchedulerCommmand`

Comment: Thanks! I know the newest version of Laravel has that, but now I'm using 4.2
But thank you. In new projects I will use a new version. :)